# C# BinaryReader performanceboost alternatives

Tags: c#, .net, performance, binaryreader

Maybe a question that has been asked many times, but still struggling with this one.

situation: C# library that contains an interpreter/parser that opens files and interprets/parses them with a huge implementation of logic with heavy use of:

```
BinaryReader
.PeekChar()
.Read()
.ReadBytes()
.ReadByte()
.BaseStream.Position
.BaseStream.Length
```

The BinaryReader receives it stream from a FileStream. File size can be several KB's, MB's or even GB's.
Pieces of extracted code:

```
    using (Stream s = File.OpenRead(path)) { // ...
    using (var br = new BinaryReader(context.Input, new ASCIIEncoding())) {  // ...


// context.Input:
public Stream Input { get; set; }
```

Parsing a file of 3MB takes about 20 seconds, which is very slow. The most time has been lost with the BinaryReader.Read() and PeekChar() functions.

I tried to optimize as much as possible, caching e.g. br.BaseStream.Length when using it in loops. Still the biggest problem is with .Read() and PeekChar() being called so much and I can't change that part of the logic.

Next I thought to increase the buffer of the filestream:

```
using (Stream s = new FileStream(pclFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096)) // profiler time: 13784
using (Stream s = new FileStream(pclFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 8192)) // profiler time: 13863
using (Stream s = new FileStream(pclFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 16384)) // profiler time: 13937
using (Stream s = new FileStream(pclFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 32768)) // profiler time: 13776
using (Stream s = new FileStream(pclFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 65536)) // profiler time: 13833
using (Stream s = new FileStream(pclFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 131072)) // profiler time: 13857
using (Stream s = new FileStream(pclFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 1000000)) // profiler time: 13746
using (Stream s = new FileStream(pclFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 2000000)) // profiler time: 13814
using (Stream s = new FileStream(pclFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 5000000)) // profiler time: 13736
```

but this didn't do much.
I thought that a bigger buffer would require less access to the disk where the BinaryReader.Read(),.PeekChar() could get an advantage. But no luck there.

Next idea was using a MemoryMappedFile and creating a stream out of it:

```
  long length = new FileInfo(path).Length;      
  using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(pclFile, FileMode.Open, "pclfile", length))
  {
    using (var viewStream = mmf.CreateViewStream(0, length, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read))
    { 
      // give this stream to the BinaryReader
    }
  }
```

A little bit of improvement, but still not good (let's say it is now 19,8seconds instead of 20seconds when profiling).

After this I believe the problem relies with the BinaryReader.
What are the best options now?
I basically need the `.Read()`, `.ReadBytes()`, `ReadByte()`, `PeekChar()`, `Position` and `Length` from a BinaryReader.

I'm on .NET Framework 4.6.2.

[image]

**update:**

using FileStream (File.OpenRead()) - BinaryReader:
[image]

using MemoryMappedViewStream - BinaryReader:
[image]

Comment: Though it would require substantially revising the logic, [`System.IO.Pipelines`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/) is worth taking a look at (designed with .NET Core in mind but available for Framework 4.6+ as well) -- it was designed to solve problems where you want to read data in chunks for performance, but can't conveniently process it in chunks in the logic (including the requirement for lookahead).

Comment: Use buffers, read into memory or use as mentioned System.IO.Pipelines. Reading byte by byte will be expensive on IO.

Comment: Read entire file into memory stream.  Then set position to zero.the read into BinaryReader and use current code.  I suspect the slow time is reading from the file in chunks.

Comment: It is the end-of-file check that kills this dead.  Use `long len = br.BaseStream.Length;` *before* you start parsing.  Bail out with `if (br.BaseStream.Position >= len) break;`  No more OS calls that need to hit the disk to check if the Length changed, x25 faster on my machine.

Comment: @HansPassant BufferedStream and modifying FileStream buffer didn't do a thing, still don't know the reason for this. I've retried again with mmf.CreateViewStream() and for some reason rebuilding it several times now benchmarks a lot better (let's say 5 to 7 seconds instead of 20 seconds). is a memorymappedviewstream ok to work with e.g. regarding memory, server vs. desktop, virtual environments, ...? (never used it before in production). How does MMF work if you try to open a file bigger than what you have of (free) RAM available?

Comment: @JosefJetmar I tried bufferdstream and tried to increase the filestream buffer, but that didn't do a thing... memorymappedfile seems to work ok now.

Comment: Using an MMF makes very little sense, the file is already buffered by the file system cache.  Don't stop until it takes no more than ~0.1 sec on a 3MB file.  I got there by wondering why you'd use PeekChar(), getting a 20 sec repro by trying it.  And getting rid of it, note how unhelpful the code snippets are to help anybody see this problem.

Comment: "I believe the problem relies with the BinaryReader". Have you checked? Step one when investigating performance problems should be to run a profiler. Even expert guesses about what part is causing problems are wrong quite often.

Comment: @HansPassant I already cached the BaseStream.Length as I found out this slows down a lot. But even with this I get speeds of 20seconds for a small file. Only by using reading the file completely in memory first (e.g. filestream copyto memorystream) or by using a MemoryMappedViewStream gives me speeds of about 5 - 7 seconds instead of 20s. I don't understand why changing the FileStream buffer in ctor doesn't improve speed as it should reduce disk IO calls, right? Are you suggesting to use FileStream and removing PeekChar logic and just using ReadChar() instead of Peeking and rewriting logic?

Comment: JonasH @HansPassant I'll try to see if I can create a repro, as the code now and test file can't be shared.

Comment: @HansPassant right now I can't create a repro solution. I have added two additional screenshots from the same piece of code. As you can see I'm parsing and reading commands, building them via stringbuilder.  Other similar functions exist (to read other types of commands). As you can see the br.Read() is very slow using a FileStream (File.OpenRead()), using MMF/MMViewStream my speed is much better. Why did you say MMF makes very little sense? How can this be done without MMF? I'm looking forward to learn more, but I understand that explaining without a good repro is my biggest mistake.